# Mine n grams of mineral using robot - JPMC Interview question

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, puzzle

Mine n grams of mineral using robot which can spend its day either by mining 1gm per day or by creating another robot per day - JPMC Interview question

- newly created robot can start its work only after one day.
- how many days/ how many robots required to mine n grams of mineral ?

ex: input 1
    output 1
    input 4
    output 3

Comment: So what's your answer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The optimal output of a robot is purely defined by how many days it has left to work. We can quite easily give an optimal recurrence:

```
def optimal_output(days):
    if days == 0: return 0
    if days == 1: return 1
    return max(optimal_output(days - 1) + 1,  # Mine.
               optimal_output(days - 1) + optimal_output(days - 2)) # Create robot.
```

We can look at the first couple terms:

```
>>> [optimal_output(n) for n in range(10)]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55]
```

Hey, that's just Fibonacci. Which makes sense because after day 3 we have that `optimal_output(days - 1) + 1` can never be higher than `optimal_output(days - 1) + optimal_output(days - 2)`, and we're left with just the recurrence of Fibonacci.

---

The above is assuming that a robot built on day 1 can only start work on day 3. If it can start work on day 2 we have the following recurrence:

```
def optimal_output(days):
    if days == 0: return 0
    if days == 1: return 1
    return max(optimal_output(days - 1) + 1,  # Mine.
               optimal_output(days - 1) + optimal_output(days - 1)) # Create robot.
```

Which simplifies to `f(1) =`, `f(n) = 2f(n-1)` or in other words, the powers of two.

Answer (score 0):

```
int findMinDaysUsingMath(int grain) {
    return (int) Math.ceil(Math.log(grain) / Math.log(2)) + 1;
}
```